# powershell get-service says no service found instead of error connecting

Tags: windows, powershell, service

this is quite weird behavior. I would say a bug in powershell.
If you have some remote machine which you can ping, but WinRM and RPC is blocked you can do

```
PS C:\Users\x_vitzur01> gsv -cn srv-trioprd-01

    gsv : Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'srv-trioprd-01'. This operation might require other privileges.
    At line:1 char:1
    + gsv -cn srv-trioprd-01
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Service], InvalidOperationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand
```

and that's fine you can see it does not work. However if you specify a service name you will get different error instead!

```
PS C:\Users\x_vitzur01> gsv -cn srv-trioprd-01 -name netlogon
gsv : Cannot find any service with service name 'netlogon'.
At line:1 char:1
+ gsv -cn srv-trioprd-01 -name netlogon
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (netlogon:String) [Get-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand
```

This message is exactly the same as if I was checking a service on an accessible machine, but the service is not there. This is very misleading as it looks like powershell actually looked at services on that machine, but it actually didn't. In such case how can I determine when the service is not there or gsv just couldn't connect? Maybe to check some special error variable?